# Test Alt key in Telerik Test Studio

Tags: telerik, automated-tests

There seems to be no way to test an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Key sequence with Test Studio. This is a very serious problem with web-based system, because <kbd>Alt</kbd> is used as the standard access key for all browsers (part of the standard access key sequence for FireFox).  When you record an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Key sequence in Test Studio, it does not work on playback.  If you then try to generate an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Key sequence with a coded step, it doesn't work because Test Studio internally converts the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Key sequence to be an <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-sequence, which none of the browsers (Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, FireFox, Safari) recognize. Three years ago the browsers would have generated an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> sequence to represent <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, but they don't do that any more.

Comment: If you agree that Telerik should fix this problem, please like my post at: 

http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/161/Feedback/Details/157432-alt-key-in-test-studio

Answer (score 0):

This now FIXED!  Get the latest hotfix for Telerik Test Studio as of May 19 if you have a commercial license.